# Why/ when should i use dojo modules?

Tags: module, dojo

I have already reada lot about writing modules, but I still do not understand exactly why should I use modules. Where is the advantage of writing the code in a module and when should I use it? Hope this Question doesn't sound silly...

Regards, Miriam

Comment: Modules are essentially equivalent to classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why? To compartmentalize related functionality so as to be reusable and maintainable.

When? There's no hard rule.  For me, I write code linearly to get the ideas out of my head as fast as possible.  At some point I get this feeling -- "whoa, this is too much code" -- and I bust up the functionality into modules.  Suddenly what was one big piece of code now becomes several, each doing one part of the overall thing.

The theoretical goal is that each module will do one thing, and do it well.  A module being an "atom" of code, the smallest unit of reuse: it does its one thing, and no other module does that one thing.

Practically speaking, I end up with modules that do the following kinds of things:

1. Models, modules that model the data in my application
2. Views, module templates that are HTML with variable substitution
3. Controllers, modules that glue views and models together.  99% of the time, views and controllers are forms
4. Managers, modules responsible for controlling parts of interaction: eg, centralized data communications, lock management,
   etc.
5. Dialogs, modules corresponding to individual dialogs
6. Toaster, a module that pops up messages